# Strange problem with Android app and library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries

I'm having some great code which I would like to share with others. I thought it would be a good idea to wrap the sharable code into an Android Library.

I'm using some foreign code, which requires me to specify this in my build.gradle for the library:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

I had a lot of problems to make some functions run, which ran successfully while they were embedded in my old MainActivity. Now, when they were in the lib it always crashed for unrelated and unclear reasons.

Until - and I admit, I don't really understand, what difference this makes - I specified exactly the same compileOptions regarding source and targetCompatibility in my app's build.gradle.

From that moment on all problems where gone.

Does that make any sense to somebody?

Comment: It appears that your app(and library module) are using java - 8 features. If you remove these options from build.gradle, what is the error?  
 https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#disable

Comment: No, the app is not using any Java 8 feature. But the lib does. The error is extremely unclear. I wasn't really able to find the real reason, since it crashed with a completely unrelated dump. If I remove Java 8 support from the library the compiler claims things like this: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
        executor.execute(() -> { . ... And if I do not have the same Java 8 source and targetCompatibility 1.8 set, then it crashes somewhere here... Sorry for being so unspecific, but I don't really kow.

Comment: Library is using java-8 features lambda expression. You need to specify the compileOptions as you mentioned above. What is the error you are getting when you include compileOptions in build.gradle?

Comment: Then of course there is no error. Please note: The library was using Java 8 compileOptions already. Just the app wasn't. That leads to a crash, even though the app was not using any Java 8 features. Only after having specified the same Java 8 compileOptions the crash was gone. This is what I don't understand. I was trying to remove Java 8 dependency from the lib to no avail (by rewriting the lambdas to the old style Runnable way). I'm having another problem now. The app is using WebRTC EglBase, which has a static interface function I need to all. This is not possible in 1.7

Comment: This is really a repeatable problem. Even with the release build. But I think the reason is the EglBase thing since it calls that static function on an interface. Will try to work around.